# Will all cores be used on an i7 when running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: sql-server-2008, multi-core, central-processing-unit

I have a server with an Intel Core i7 processor (4 cores). If I view processor activity in Task Manager I see that there are 8 cores. I believe that this is because of hyperthreading (please correct me if I'm wrong).

SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard will use a maximum of 4 CPUs when compared to SQL Server Enterprise which uses a maximum of 8 CPUs.

My question: Will the standard version of SQL Server fully utilize all available CPUs on this server? i.e. Will it see 4 or 8 CPUs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit in SQL Server 2008 Standard for processors is per socket, not per core. For more info, check out the [SQL Server 2008 page at Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions.aspx). Specifically, the "[SQL Server 2008 R2 Editions Overview](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/F/C/FFC6D450-A0A2-4916-80EA-B83F7BCDF250/SQLServer2008R2EditionsDatasheet_Aug10%5B1%5D.pdf)" PDF document. From the document:

> With increasing hardware innovations, Microsoft continues to be the
>   only major database vendor who does not price per core for multi-core
>   processors

Yes, SQL Server 2008 Standard will use all 8 cores. It could use a hundred cores on a single-socket license if such a CPU existed.

Comment: Please note though that this does *not* apply to SQL Server 2012, as it has switched to a per-core licensing model. Although 1 socket == 4 cores when you upgrade, so in *this* case it's about the same (just disable hyperthreading).

Comment: Yes, 2012 includes value added licensing suck.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. If load is placed on only four cores, the scheduler is smart enough to make sure that the load is on one logical core for each physical core. And hyper-threading typically gives you at best an additional 15% of performance. Loading a virtual core robs the other virtual core that shares that physical core of resources such as execution units, I/O bandwidth, L2 cache space, and so on. So they don't run at anywhere near full speed.

So even in the worst imaginable case, it would mean about 15% of your CPU couldn't be used by SQL server itself. But when SQL server is doing things, so will the OS be -- handling network and disk interrupts, managing memory, and so on. In any realistic case, that will be around 20% of the CPU load, and that can use the other virtual cores. So you're fighting over essentially nothing.